# Group words by letter length?

Tags: python, python-3.x

im attempting to group words by their length (e.g. number of characters in each words) so that the expected output can look something like this:
3:500, 4:232, 5:664, 6,:6311, 7:5553 etc.

I have gotten the number of times certain words appear in the .txt file, though I don't know how to group these words into a tally of the number of letters in each words.

I don't know how to explain further, but say for example if a three letter word (can be any three letter word like 'and', or 'the') appears in a .txt file 500 times, it will print the result as 3:500, and so on for 4 letter words, 5 letter words... and so on! Is there any way i can modify this existing code so that this can be possible?

code:

```
fname= input('Enter file: ')
#if len(fname) < 1: fname = 'LOTR.txt'
try:
    fhand = open(fname, encoding = "utf8")
    d = dict()
    for line in fhand:
        words = line.split()
        for word in words:
            d[word] = d.get(word, 0) + 1

    print(d)
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("File not found")
except Exception as e:
    print("Other error occurred", e)
```

expected output:

```
{8: 6058, 1: 6310, 10: 2046, 7: 12071, 4: 40364, 2: 31147, 9: 3505, 3: 45148, 5: 25333, 6: 15778, 11: 806, 0: 54, 12: 429, 13: 227, 14: 64, 15: 37, 19: 17, 18: 5, 20: 2, 16: 14, 17: 6, 22: 1, 21: 2, 23: 2, 37: 1, 33: 1, 36: 2, 34: 1}
```

current output

```
, 'torture.': 1, 'doubt:': 4, 'slow,': 2, 'sneaking': 1, 'mile': 15, 'mile,': 4, 'south,': 8, 'Mordor.’': 2, 'silence': 15, 'beating.': 2, 'shears': 2, 'heard.': 8, 'Mordor,’': 2, 'draws': 4, 'gather': 3, 'summons.': 1, 'whispering': 6, 'hatred': 3,
```

cheers for anyone who can help!

Comment: Have you tried collections module?

Comment: i cant import libraries for this task! any ways i can do it without importing a counter?

Comment: yes I will update my answer

Comment: you just need to set the key to the length of the word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
# Open the file in read mode
text = open("sample.txt", "r")

# Create an empty dictionary
d = dict()

# Loop through each line of the file
for line in text:
    # Remove the leading spaces and newline character
    line = line.strip()

    # Convert the characters in line to
    # lowercase to avoid case mismatch
    line = line.lower()

    # Split the line into words
    words = line.split(" ")

    # Iterate over each word in line
    for word in words:
        # Check if the word is already in dictionary
        if len(word) in d:
            # Increment count of word by 1
            d[len(word)] = d[len(word)] + 1
        else:
            # Add the word to dictionary with count 1
            d[len(word)] = 1

# Print the contents of dictionary
for key in list(d.keys()):
    print(key, ":", d[key])
```

My sample.txt file consists of
`Mango banana apple pear Banana grapes strawberry Apple pear mango banana Kiwi apple mango strawberry`

My output is

```
5 : 6
6 : 4
4 : 3
10 : 2
```

5 lettered words `Apple` and `mango` occurred 6 times combined

6 lettered words `banana`  and  `grapes` occurred 4 times combined

4 lettered words `pear` and `kiwi` occurred 3 times combined

10 lettered word `strawberry` occurred 2 times

Comment: Thanks man, worked like a charm! you're a lifesaver!

Answer (score 1):

You can create another dictionary that uses the word length as keys and increment values when you see another word of the same length.

```
fname = 'temp.txt'

try:
    fhand = open(fname, encoding='utf-8')
    
    d = dict()
    
    for line in fhand:
        words = line.split()
        
        for word in words:
            d[word] = d.get(word, 0) + 1

# Edit

    word_len = dict()

    for word in d:
        print(d[word])
        word_len[len(word)] = word_len.get(len(word), 0) + d[word] 

    print(word_len)

# End of edit

except FileNotFoundError:
    print('File not found')

except Exception as e:
    print('Other error occurred', e)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,

```
from collections import Counter
words = ['test','demo','test1','demo','nandy','azure','cloud','azure','dev','prod','test']
words_count = list(map(len,words))
data = Counter(words_count)    
print(data) # Counter({4: 5, 5: 5, 3: 1})
```

Or without any modules do,

```
words = ['test','demo','test1','demo','nandy','azure','cloud','azure','dev','prod','test']
words_count = list(map(len,words))
expected = {}
for count in words_count:
    expected[count] = expected.get(count,0)+1
print(expected) # {4: 5, 5: 5, 3: 1}
```

Actual Code in a shorter way or smart way,

```
fname= input('Enter file: ')
#if len(fname) < 1: fname = 'LOTR.txt'
try:
    fhand = open(fname, encoding = "utf8")
    d = {}
    with open(fname) as fhand:
        for line in fhand:
            for count in map(len,line.split()):
                d[count] = d.get(count, 0) + 1
    print(d)
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("File not found")
except Exception as e:
    print("Other error occurred", e)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set the key to the word but to the length of the word.
So the code would be:

```
fname= input('Enter file: ')
#if len(fname) < 1: fname = 'LOTR.txt'
try:
    fhand = open(fname, encoding = "utf8")
    d = dict()
    for line in fhand:
        words = line.split()
        for word in words:
            try:
                d[len(word)] = d[len(word)] + 1
            except KeyError:
                d[len(word)] = 1

    print(d)
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("File not found")
except Exception as e:
    print("Other error occurred", e)
```

Comment: Hey man, this appears to be the thing im after, but its returning keyerror: 8 on line 9 (d[len(word)]= d[len(word)]+1

Comment: Sorry I forgot u need to surround it with I try / except I will update the answer shortly. I just need to finish something